# Bootstrap data-loading-text to contain quotes

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**My question:**
How do I get quotes to work within a data-loading-text attribute on a button like this:

```
data-loading-text="<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"> Loading..."
```

**Background:**

Using the [Bootstrap "loading" example from here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons) - I have a button which, when clicked, changes to "loading..." as intended

```
<button type="button" id="loading-example-btn" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary">
   Click me
</button>
```

It works with the following script and changes "Click me" to "Loading..."

```
<script>
  $('#loading-example-btn').click(function () {
    var btn = $(this)
    btn.button('loading')
  });
</script>
```

To complicate matters - the button text is actually generated as part of a PHP macro:

```
return '<button id="submitaction" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Loading..." type="submit">Click Me</button>';
```

But now I want to include a Font Awesome 'spinning' icon as part of the loading text. The problem is this is the code I need to include:

```
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin">
```

And because of the " " in there - I cannot simply put it in the data-loading-text field, otherwise the quotes " " causes the text to be rendered incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try escaping the `<i>` class attribute with backslashes, like

```
return '<button id="submitaction" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="<i class=\'fa fa-spinner fa-spin\'>Loading...</i>" type="submit">Click Me</button>';
```

This should output:

```
<button id="submitaction" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'>Loading...</i>" type="submit">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks - I knew I was missing something obvious. I'll accept the answer in 10mins when it lets me.